# How to find the subarray with given sum

Tags: python

Code is below

find the subarray which matches given sum

arr is given array, s is the sum

```
def getsub(arr,s):
    result = []
    for x in range(len(arr)):
        result.append(arr[x])
        while sum(result) > s:
            result.pop(0)
        if sum(result) == s:
            return result
arr = [4, 1, 6, 5, 2, 3]
s=5
getsub(arr,s)
```

I got only `[4,1]` only the `first occurance`

But actual output is `[4,1] [5] [2,3]`

Can i do it in o(n) time. I have done with (o(n3))TC by printing all the subarray and check the sum which is equal to s. which is not optimal

Comment: I'm not sure if it is doable in *O(n)* time since it can have multiple combinations, and the number of elements in the subarray seems to be varying

Comment: @ThePyGuy Agreed, if it was just 2 numbers each it would be easy in O(n), but with subarrays of any size, id assume its O(n!) or something like that

Comment: Feels like a DP problem...

Comment: We can achieve **O(n)** using **Hashing** or **Slidding Window** technique. For further details you can check my answer. Happy coding :)

Comment: @Maws You can check my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There could be 2 possible approach for this.

1. Slidding Window
2. Hashing

**Slidding Window:**

```
# Function to find sublist having a given sum using hashing sliding window
def find_sub_list_using_sliding_window(arr, expected_sum):
 
    # maintains the sum of the current window
    windowSum = 0
 
    # maintain a window `[low, high-1]`
    [low, high] = [0, 0]

    # store pairs equivalent to `expected_sum`
    sum_list = []
 
    # consider every sublist starting from `low` index
    for low in range(len(arr)):
 
        # if the current window's sum is less than the given sum,
        # then add elements to the current window from the right
        while windowSum < expected_sum and high < len(arr):
            windowSum += arr[high]
            high = high + 1
 
        # if the current window's sum is equal to the given sum
        if windowSum == expected_sum:
            s_index = low
            e_index = high - 1
            sum_list.append([arr[s_index], arr[e_index]] if s_index != e_index else [arr[s_index]])
 
        # at this point, the current window's sum is more than the given sum.
        # remove the current element (leftmost element) from the window
        windowSum -= arr[low]

    return sum_list
```

> The time complexity of the above solution is **O(n)** and doesn’t require any extra space, where **n** is the size of the input.

---

**Hashing:**

```
# Function to find sublist having a given sum using hashing
def find_sub_list_using_hashing(arr, expected_sum):
 
    # insert `(0, -1)` pair into the set to handle the case when
    # a sublist with the given sum starts from index 0
    num_dict = {0: -1}
 
    # keep track of the sum of elements so far
    sum_so_far = 0
    
    # store pairs equivalent to `expected_sum`
    sum_list = []
    
    # traverse the given list
    for i in range(len(arr)):
 
        # update sum_so_far
        sum_so_far += arr[i]
 
        # if `sum_so_far - expected_sum` is seen before,
        # we have found the sublist with sum equal to `expected_sum`
        if (sum_so_far - expected_sum) in num_dict:
            s_index = num_dict.get(sum_so_far - expected_sum) + 1
            sum_list.append([arr[s_index], arr[i]] if s_index != i else [arr[i]])
 
        # insert (current sum, current index) pair into the dictionary
        num_dict[sum_so_far] = i

    return sum_list
```

> The time complexity of the above solution is **O(n)** and requires **O(n)** extra space, where **n** is the size of the input.

---

**Driver Code:**

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
 
    # a list of positive integers
    arr = [4, 1, 6, 5, 2, 3]
    expected_sum = 5

    sum_list = find_sub_list_using_sliding_window(arr, expected_sum)
    print(f'Find Sub List Equivalen to a Given Sum Using Sliding Window: {sum_list}')

    sum_list = find_sub_list_using_hashing(arr, expected_sum)
    print(f'Find Sub List Equivalen to a Given Sum Using Hasing: {sum_list}')
```

**Output:**

```
Find Sub List Equivalen to a Given Sum Using Sliding Window: [[4, 1], [5], [2, 3]]
Find Sub List Equivalen to a Given Sum Using Hasing: [[4, 1], [5], [2, 3]]
```

Comment: can you tell me how you become master in dynamic programming

Comment: I not master in DP, just know basics. :). Practice can make things easier for you. :)

Answer (score 1):

This is the fastest structure I can think of:

```
def getsub(arr,s):
    results = []
    result = []
    for x in range(len(arr)):
        result.append(arr[x])
        while sum(result) > s:
            result.pop(0)
        if sum(result) == s:
            results.append(result); result = []
    return results
```

```
arr = [4, 1, 6, 5, 2, 3]
s=5
print(getsub(arr,s))  # [[4, 1], [5], [2, 3]]
```

It doesn't support nested or multiple combinations.

Comment: We can achieve O(n) using Hashing or Slidding Window technique

Comment: @Sabil Learned some things from your ans.

Comment: if multiple compination, then it will not become subarray right?

Comment: @Sabil, can you post the answer

Comment: No, it doesn't support multiple combinations :(

Answer (score 1):

Your algorithm running time is O(n) but if you want to better optimize the constants you can use this one which doesn't keep calling `sum()` over your sublist.

```
def summing(arr, n, sum_):
    
    current_sum = arr[0]
    start = 0
    i = 1
    while i <= n:
        while current_sum > sum_ and start < i-1:
            current_sum = current_sum - arr[start]
            start += 1

        if current_sum == sum_:
            print ("Sum found at: {} and {}".format(start, i-1))
            return 1

        if i < n:
            current_sum = current_sum + arr[i]
        i += 1
    print ("None found")
    return 0

arr = [15, 2, 4, 8]
length = len(arr)
sum_ = 6
summing(arr, length, sum_)
```

NOTE that these programs will fail if arrays indexes that can make this sum are not contiguous but this is the best i can think of as this problem is considered as [NP complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) if you don't require that sub array indexes to be contiguous in which elements can be any where in the array.

Answer (score 0):

JAVA Try this approach and construct a recursion tree to understand better

public class Combination_sum {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int arr[]= {4, 1, 6, 5, 2, 3};
    int target=5;
    List<Integer> ds=new ArrayList<Integer>();

    List<List<Integer>> ans = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
    findComb(0, target, ds, arr, ans);
    System.out.println(ans);


}

public static void findComb(int index,int target,List<Integer> ds,int arr[],List<List<Integer>> ans ){

    if (index>arr.length-1) {

        if (target==0) {
            ans.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(ds));
        }

        return;
    }

    if (arr[index]<=target) {

        ds.add(arr[index]);
        findComb(index, target-arr[index], ds, arr, ans); // take the number at that index
        ds.remove(ds.size()-1);

    }

        findComb(index+1, target, ds, arr, ans); // do not take the number at that index and move forward

}
```

}